# Python sub with conditional argument

Tags: python, subprocess

i wrote the following sub:

```
def scrapetable(link, xpath, browser=openchrome()):
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    browser.get(link)
    html = browser.find_element( By.XPATH , xpath).get_attribute('outerHTML')
    df = pd.read_html(html)
    browser.quit()
    return df[0]
```

as you can see, the browser argument is optional.

i want to execute the browser.quit() only when browser was not given as input (and the sub opened the broswer itself)

how would i go about doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't put `openchrome()` as a default value. Defaults are evaluated when the function is defined, not when it's called.

Use `None` as the default. Then you can check if it was supplied, and conditionally close it.

```
def scrapetable(link, xpath, browser=None):
    need_to_close = False
    if not browser:
        browser = openchrome()
        need_to_close = True
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    browser.get(link)
    html = browser.find_element( By.XPATH , xpath).get_attribute('outerHTML')
    df = pd.read_html(html)
    if need_to_close:
        browser.quit()
    return df[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

You just have to change your default argument to `None`:

```
def scrapetable(link, xpath, browser=None):
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    if browser == None: 
        browser = openchrome()
    browser.get(link)
    html = browser.find_element( By.XPATH , xpath).get_attribute('outerHTML')
    df = pd.read_html(html)
    browser.quit()
    return df[0]
```

This will instantiate the browser if not defined and will receive it correctly if defined.

Comment: This still calls `browser.quit()` if a browser was given as input, which is not what was asked.